# c++ overwriting file data?

Tags: c++, file-io

I am trying to run a program to replace certain data within a file. The relevant parts of the file attempting to be replaced look like the following:

```
1 Information 15e+10

2 Information 2e+16

3 Information 6e+2
```

And so on.

The files in question can be very large in the multiple gigabyte range and to my understanding because of this using a buffer of the whole file and rewriting the whole file is impossible/unreasonable. Well that is all fine I just want to replace the values (ex. the `15e+10`).

This all works fine with simple `ios::in|ios::out` and `tellp()` if I am replacing the value with a similar sized value (`15e+10`->`12e+12`) or even if its a smaller size as I can simply add an extra space which can be ignored down the line (ex. `15e+10`->`4e+10` ). But I am running into the problem if I need to replace the value with a value whose length is longer than already in the file (ex. `6e+2`->`16e+10`) it will write over the new line character or start writing over the information in the next line.

I have searched on the forums and everyone says you can either overwrite in the file, you can append to the end of the file, or you can buffer and recreate the whole file. Is there anyway I can achieve my goal of overwriting the value correctly without having to recreate the file?

If not then how can I have 2 files open (1 input 1 output) to do this if multiple files in question are too large for the memory?

*Note:* I would also like to avoid using `boost::` as I need to be able to run this on a system without the *boost* library.

Comment: You do not need to have the entire file in memory.  You only need to have a single record in memory at any given time.  However, using variable-length records that need to be updated in-place for files of that size is pretty much guaranteed to be a performance nightmare.  Fixed-length records would be the simplest solution.

Comment: Not using a few-gigabyte-sized text files could be another option.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by I only need 1 record in memory at a time? I thought (easily could be wrong) that having a file opened meant that the information you were reading from it in whichever method chosen was all stored in memory, and having a 2nd file open to write to would make that take twice the space. This definitely answers my question if it doesn't and the only part stored in memory is whatever was read in which only has to be a line at a time. And Fixed-Length would be nice but with significant variations (more than the example) it seemed more reasonable at the time to choose not.

Comment: Didn't have room in the last comment, but thank you guys for the responses! I will continue checking and any details or code example are always appreciated! I consider myself a fairly sufficient programmer but have always hated the in's and out's of file I/O, lol

Answer (score 1):

Open a stream to read from the input (IN) file and a second stream (OUT) to write to a new output (tmp) file.

Read from IN and write to OUT. When you get  a value from IN that you want to replace write the replacement to OUT instead of the value you got from IN.

When parsing is complete replace the first file with the second (tmp) file.

Would this work for you?

Comment: I like the idea, but in that case I have to have both files to be opened at the same time file1.open(ios::in) and file2.open(ios::out) which means they would be stored in memory so you can access them quickly, correct? In which case I would need to make the files significantly smaller or I would be required to use a super computer with >> 8GB of RAM.

Comment: @JCline - No, both files are not stored in memory.  The C++ file methods and the operating system API beneath it will manage buffering for you.  You can safely disregard the file sizes as far as memory usage goes.

Answer (score 0):

Use [lseek()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html)/fseek() for "jump" to a given position in a file.

Comment: How does that solve the *overwrite* issue (third case in the OP) ?

Comment: You should set up a fixed length storage space for every item, e.g. 12 byte, then you don't have to worry about various item lengths. When a data is shorter than 12 byte, there will be some slack.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `seekp` to go to the location and rewrite it with `<<`

Example:

> **example.txt** ( |?| = 1 byte of data )
>
> |A|B|C|\n|1|2|3|D|E|F|\n|4|5|6|

```
//Somewhere in the code

fstream file;

open("example.txt");

//Somehow find the character distance and store it into "distance"

seekp(distance);//If distance = 0, it will go to "A" like rewind() but easier for me
```

If the distance is 4, the next character will be overwritten is `1`

```
file << "987";
```

And the file will be

> |A|B|C|\n|**9**|**8**|**7**|D|E|F|\n|4|5|6|

**BUT** the only problem here is when you need to **increase/decrease the size:**

**Increase:**

You will **overwrite** the other character so you need to create a temp string to store it the rest of data or separate it into smaller chunk if the data is too large like

> |A|B|C|\n|**9**|**8**|**7**|D|E|F|\n|4|5|6|

```
string tempstring;
seekp(distance);
file >> tempstring;
seekp(distance);
file << content << tempstring;  //content is the data
```

**Decrease:**

The easiest solution is to write **NULL character** `\0` to the excess space like

> |A|B|C|\n|**1**|**\0**|**\0**|D|E|F|\n|4|5|6|

The only **side-effect** is the file size is the same as before